# How can I erase the window background in an owner drawn static control?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am currently developing a kind of "WinMerge" clone, and currently I am trying to implement a custom scrollbar which should later represent both compared files as a rectangle in the background each.

This is what it looks like at the startup:

[image]

However, after scrolling around a little bit, this is what I end up with:

[image]

As you can clearly see, only those parts look correct which I explicitely paint over in my paint routine:

```
void LocationPane::OnPaint(CDCHandle dc)
{
    DefWindowProc();

    dc = GetDC();

    DrawLocationPaneFigures(dc);
}
```

This is how my control is configured in my .rc file:

```
CONTROL         "",IDC_LOCATIONPANE,"Static",SS_OWNERDRAW | SS_NOTIFY | WS_BORDER | WS_GROUP,7,21,91,541
```

As you can see, it is an owner drawn control.

How can I erase the background for this control while repainting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static control with [`SS_OWNERDRAW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760773(v=vs.85).aspx) style receives a [`WM_DRAWITEM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775923(v=vs.85).aspx) message when it needs to be redrawn.

So first you need to replace your `OnPaint()` handler by a handler for `WM_DRAWITEM`. Instead of calling `GetDC()` use the device context supplied to you in the [`DRAWITEMSTRUCT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/bb775802(v=vs.85).aspx).

To erase the background it's generally best to do it as part of the regular painting code to reduce flickering (by calling [`FillRect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162719(v=vs.85).aspx) for instance).

I suggest to always draw the **whole client area** of your control. Then you may handle `WM_ERASEBKGND` to return `TRUE` without calling `DefWindowProc()` to reduce flickering even more.

Comment: Is there any prerequisite required to receive WM_DRAWITEM? I just tried to switch to that message, but I am not receiving it. Maybe I should note that LocationPane is a custom subclass of CStatic.

Comment: @Sossenbinder None that I know of.

Comment: The FillRect() function fulfilled the requirement though, I am just using it in the Paint routine for now